# How to access the current layer in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have an iphone app built with cocos2d and need to access the current layer from another class. I have a HelloWorldLayer and a Cannon and I need to access the HelloWorldLayer from my Cannon node. How can I access the HelloWorldLayer? I have tried creating a static instance of my layer like below but it adds dealloc problems that I can't seem to fix. How can I access my current layer from another class? Please help?

```
static HelloWorldLayer* helloWorldLayerInstance;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always access the current layers at any point in time by getting the current running scene and then getting the children of that scene which is usually one or more layers.  So to get the currently active layers you'll want something like...

```
CCArray* layers = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene].children
```

Then you can iterate through the children to get the layer you want.

P.S. Why do you need to have your hellowWorldLayerInstance as a static variable?  This may be cause for a separate question/discussion but I am curious.

Answer (score 0):

Rob's answer is perfect for any scenarios.

But if your `Cannon` is added as a child to your `HelloWorldLayer`, you can simply get to `HelloWorldLayer` from inside `Cannon` by accessing the `parent` property.

For example:

```
// somewhere inside @implementation Cannon
HelloWorldLayer *layer = (HelloWorldLayer *)self.parent;
```